# Software Center can't install Opera, Internal error!

Tags: software-installation, appcenter

I am using elementary OS freya *0.3.2*

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary OS
Description:    elementary OS Freya
Release:    0.3.2
Codename:   freya
```

I have downloaded Opera `.deb` from their official site. When I tried from software center:

[image: Imgur]

From terminal:

```
ravan@ravan:~/Downloads$ software-center opera-stable_34.0.2036.25_amd64.deb

** (software-center:10987): WARNING **: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-C4cCKJjSeX: Connection refused
2015-12-26 13:40:04,684 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-12-26 13:40:05,054 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
2015-12-26 13:40:05,056 - softwarecenter.plugin - INFO - activating plugin '<module 'webapps_activation' from '/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/plugins/webapps_activation.pyc'>'
2015-12-26 13:40:05,109 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - INFO - aptcache.open()
2015-12-26 13:40:05,595 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - error creating bsddb: '(22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')' (corrupted?)
2015-12-26 13:40:05,595 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - ERROR - trying to repair DB failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 358, in _save_review_stats_cache_blocking
self._dump_bsddbm_for_unity(outfile, outdir)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/backend/reviews/__init__.py", line 377, in _dump_bsddbm_for_unity
0600)
DBInvalidArgError: (22, 'Invalid argument -- BDB0054 illegal flag combination specified to DB_ENV->open')
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 61 was not found when attempting to remove it
 return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
2015-12-26 13:40:07,099 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.views.lobbyview - WARNING - skipping exhibit for: 'u'leadwerks\r\nleadwerks-indie'' not available
/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/appdetailsview.py:2030: Warning: Source ID 135 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main_iteration()
2015-12-26 13:40:07,224 - softwarecenter.fixme - WARNING - logs to the root logger: '('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py', 589, 'call_async')'
2015-12-26 13:40:07,223 - dbus.connection - ERROR - Unable to set arguments ([None], [''], [''], [''], [''], ['']) according to signature None: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know which D-Bus type to use to encode type "NoneType"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 489, in _inline_callbacks
result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1626, in _run_transaction_helper
timeout=_APTDAEMON_DBUS_TIMEOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 137, in __call__
**keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 584, in call_async
    message.append(signature=signature, *args)
TypeError: Don't know which D-Bus type to use to encode type "NoneType"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 489, in _inline_callbacks
  result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1626, in _run_transaction_helper
timeout=_APTDAEMON_DBUS_TIMEOUT)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 137, in __call__
**keywords)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 584, in call_async
message.append(signature=signature, *args)
  TypeError: Don't know which D-Bus type to use to encode type "NoneType"
2015-12-26 13:40:07,225 - softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache - ERROR - simulate failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1591, in on_error
    error.raise_exception()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 489, in _inline_callbacks
  result = gen.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/aptdaemon/client.py", line 1626, in _run_transaction_helper
    timeout=_APTDAEMON_DBUS_TIMEOUT)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/proxies.py", line 137, in __call__
**keywords)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dbus/connection.py", line 584, in call_async
   message.append(signature=signature, *args)
 TypeError: Don't know which D-Bus type to use to encode type "NoneType"
 2015-12-26 13:40:07,341 - softwarecenter.backend.spawn_helper - WARNING - exit code 1 from helper for '['/usr/share/software-center/piston_generic_helper.py', '--datadir', '/usr/share/software-center/', 'SoftwareCenterRecommenderAPI', 'recommend_app', '{"pkgname": null}']'
2015-12-26 13:40:07,341 - softwarecenter.backend.spawn_helper - WARNING - got error from helper: 'ERROR:__main__:urclient_apps
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/share/software-center/piston_generic_helper.py", line 147, in <module>
  piston_reply = f(**kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston_mini_client/validators.py", line 41, in wrapper
   "Argument '%s' must be a string" % varname)
 ValidationException: Argument 'pkgname' must be a string

  2015-12-26 13:40:07,342 - softwarecenter.db.categories - WARNING - Error while accessing the recommender service: ERROR:__main__:urclient_apps
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/piston_generic_helper.py", line 147, in <module>
  piston_reply = f(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston_mini_client/validators.py", line 41, in wrapper
   "Argument '%s' must be a string" % varname)
ValidationException: Argument 'pkgname' must be a string

2015-12-26 13:40:07,342 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.widgets.recommendations - WARNING - Error while accessing the recommender agent: ERROR:__main__:urclient_apps
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/share/software-center/piston_generic_helper.py", line 147, in <module>
 piston_reply = f(**kwargs)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/piston_mini_client/validators.py", line 41, in wrapper
  "Argument '%s' must be a string" % varname)
ValidationException: Argument 'pkgname' must be a string

/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 215 was not found when attempting to remove it
 Gtk.main()
/usr/bin/software-center:184: Warning: Source ID 213 was not found when attempting to remove it
  Gtk.main()
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/overrides/GLib.py:535: Warning: Source ID 20 was not found when attempting to remove it
 return super(MainContext, self).iteration(may_block)
2015-12-26 13:40:12,125 - softwarecenter.db.utils - INFO - software-center-agent finished with status 0
```

---

```
ravan@ravan:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i opera-stable_34.0.2036.25_amd64.deb
[sudo] password for ravan: 
Selecting previously unselected package opera-stable.
(Reading database ... 217479 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack opera-stable_34.0.2036.25_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking opera-stable (34.0.2036.25) ...
dpkg-deb (subprocess): cannot copy archive member from 'opera-stable_34.0.2036.25_amd64.deb' to decompressor pipe: unexpected end of file or stream
dpkg-deb (subprocess): decompressing archive member: lzma error: unexpected end of input
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess <decompress> returned error exit status 2
dpkg: error processing archive opera-stable_34.0.2036.25_amd64.deb (--install):
cannot copy extracted data for './usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera.pak' to '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opera/opera.pak.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
  opera-stable_34.0.2036.25_amd64.deb
```

Comment: JFTR: I was able to install the same version using software center without problem (Freya 0.3.2 as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is  a problem with the download and the file got corrupted. I have installed it manually using [Ubuntu documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser).

I have manually added opera apt-repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/ stable non-free'
wget -qO- https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then installed opera,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install opera-stable
```